# Scrollbar in #questions-table on user profile pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image: Minecraft?]

Chrome/Win 10.0.648.119 beta.

For some reason, if I open the developer tools and *disable* the `.user-stats-table { overflow-x: hidden; }` rule, the scrollbar disappears.

Disabling the `.fr { float: right; }` rule also makes the scrollbar go away, but it *stays gone when I re-enable the rule*.

Probably just some weirdness caused by running the beta version of a browser?

I should also note that this started appearing a few days ago, but I didn't bother posting until now.

Comment: No repro. IE8 on XP.

Comment: I've had this for the longest time.

Comment: I can't repro this in Chrome 9.0.597.102 OSX. Is Chrome 10 still beta?

Comment: @Jin: Chrome 10 is no longer beta as of today. I still get the scrollbar.

Answer (score 3):

I put in a fix, based on badp's suggestion. the change should be on live tomorrow. please mark this as accepted if you see the fix working.

Comment: I'm now getting a horizontal scroll bar. (Firefox 3.6.15)

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually getting a horizontal scrollbar myself as well, like @Brandon. I'm on IE8 with XP.

Comment: Same here, the vertical scrollbar has been replaced with a horizontal one.

Comment: Fix two.oh is coming soon.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this happens, but turning off the `overflow-x` rule for `.user-stats-table` fixes this.

Comment: Removing the "width: 100%" that's set in the `style` attribute of the tables there also seems to work, not sure what's going on there.